# How can I apply mobile css query to my div with background image?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have a html div

```
<div class="col-md-6 elo">       
    <div class="col col-1-2" style="animation-delay: -42s;">
      <div class="content animated fadeIn delayed">
        <div class="my-video">
            <video class="video--app" id="myVideo" autoplay="" muted="" preload="auto">
                <source src="./img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
      </div>               
    </div>
</div>
```

with a background image set in css code:

```
.my-video {
    margin: auto;
    width: 372px;
    height: 705px;
    background-image: url(../img/myvideo@2x.png);
    background-size: 368px 705px;
}
```

When user enters my page he sees the mp4 played in a frame `myvideo@2x.png`. But when he shrinks the webpage, I hide the video by applying mobile query:

```
@media (max-width:600px){

  .video--app{
    display:none;
  }
```

and I also would like to change the size of the background image, so its width is equal to 80% of the visible area (height should be proportional to width). I tried setting:

```
background-size: auto;
```

to `my-video` but it didn't work. How can I fix it then? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set  `background-size:100%` instead and add `width:100%`

```css
.my-video {
  margin: auto;
  width: 372px;
  height: 705px;
  background: url(http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4973/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone6/plus/iphone6-plus-box-silver-2014_GEO_US?wid=478&hei=595&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=J8El53) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .video--app {
    display: none;
  }
  .my-video {
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 elo">
      <div class="col col-1-2" style="animation-delay: -42s;">
        <div class="content animated fadeIn delayed">
          <div class="my-video">
            <video class="video--app" id="myVideo" autoplay="" muted="" preload="auto">
              <source src="./img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm what about setting width and height? Setting only background-size to 100% didn't work in my case...

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle to help you better?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vv95Lmv6/ check it out, when I shrink the output I wanted the iphone to get smaller to fit the screen, but it doesn't shrink...

Comment: Thanks, one more question though - if you don't override height in media queries - what happens with it? Is it not taken into consideration on smaller displays?

Comment: What I mean by previous comment is a problem with several textures one below the other, check out here https://jsfiddle.net/vv95Lmv6/1/ when you shrink the screen there're several iphones... is there a way to make visible only one?

Comment: did you run my snippet? I used `no-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

You can use background size as cover.

```
.my-video {
    margin: auto;
    width: 372px;
    height: 705px;
    background-image: url(../img/myvideo@2x.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```